# Using OpenID with WCF and no browser, is it possible?

Tags: wcf, openid

From most of the reading I've done on OpenID, it seems a browser may be required.  I'm writing a WCF app and wanted to use OpenID as the authentication method, but my app is not a web app.  Is it possible to use WCF and OpenID together without requiring a web browser?

Comment: Sorry for this very late comment. But by "no browser" do you mean display your own login window and let users enter their, for example, Google username and password? If I were a user, I would NEVER give out my user/password like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While OpenID can tout in its spec independence from cookies and such because the spec doesn't actually mandate how those things are used, in reality I've never seen a good OpenID solution for anything besides logging into a web site, which is really its primary use case.

However there is a good way to go and still use WCF and OpenID.  Add OAuth to the mix.  The [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenid.googlecode.com/) library has a sample that shows how a WCF client can get authorized to call a WCF service via OAuth, where at the service-side the user uses OpenID to log in as part of the authorization process.

So basically if you WCF app needs to "log in" in order to call the WCF service, as part of a one-time setup:

1. The app pops up a browser where the user sees the WCF service web site (the OAuth Service Provider)
2. The user logs in with their OpenID (although the user may already be logged in, in which case they can skip this step)
3. The OAuth SP asks the user "do you want to authorize this [wcf app] to access this site?"
4. The user says yes, and closes the browser.
5. The WCF app now has access, thanks to the OAuth protocol, to the WCF service.

This works because behind the scenes, when the user says "yes" to the service through the web browser, a special machine-friendly credential is assigned to the WCF app, which it uses with every WCF service call the a similar way a username/password would be.

Check out the DotNetOpenAuth library.  It has the sample and everything you should need to get this working.

Comment: This post was very insightful, thanks!  I'll take a look at DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: @andrew-arnott I know this one is very old. The site shutted down, do you have a new link ? I searched and found several repo on github but I don't know if it's the same

Comment: The project is now at https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth, but it isn't maintained any more.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [OpenID Authentication 2.0 Specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html), I seem to have arrived at an answer:

> **While nothing in the protocol requires JavaScript or modern browsers**, the authentication scheme plays nicely with "AJAX"-style setups. This means an end user can prove their Identity to a Relying Party without having to leave their current Web page.
>
> OpenID Authentication uses only standard HTTP(S) requests and responses, so **it does not require any special capabilities of the User-Agent or other client software**. OpenID is not tied to the use of cookies or any other specific mechanism of Relying Party or OpenID Provider session management. Extensions to User-Agents can simplify the end user interaction, though are not required to utilize the protocol.

Now I just need to figure out a clever way to get it to work with a WCF-based relying party...

Answer (score 1):

Take a [OpenIdMembershipProvider](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenIDMembership) (maybe others exist).
[Then configure Message security in WCF, with Username authentication, then you can use the ASPNET MembershipProvider to authenticate your user.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx)
I don't think you can find an easier solution ;)

Comment: This sounds really simple.  No browser interaction is required?

Comment: No browser interaction is required, but I don't know how to use this provider, maybe he has some depedencies on ASP.NET which make you to activate the compatibility mode.
see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx 
There is several OpenIDMembershipProvider which exists, I didn't test any of them. Assuming they work as expected, you just have to "plug" your openIdMembershipProvider, and then say WCF to use it to authenticate requests.