# Can I authenticate in a webservice using OpenID?

Tags: c#, web-services, openid

This webservice is written in C#, and I want to use an OpenID to authenticate.

This authentication request will be called by a WPF, and an asp.net applicantion.
the webservice will then try to authenticate in OpenID server, and in this case I use OpenID-LDAP software.

The big problem is how to use OpenID without showing the web page to login (the webservice is who is going to inform user and password)?

Comment: You didn't mention WCF so I'm not voting to close, but [this earlier question on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843529/using-openid-with-wcf-and-no-browser-is-it-possible) discussed merging a WCF webservice with OpenID.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386973/web-service-authentication-using-openid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open ID will, by design, not work here ... because it works by delegating the authentication to another party (when it shows the open ID provider's website to let the user log in). What you probably want to do is authenticate the user once in your WPF app, and then set up some sort of authentication token between your app and the webservice.